# Copy to dynamically created rows in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy paste values from four columns in one worksheet to four columns of another worksheet but dynamically add rows as the number of items will not be the same every time.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    With Worksheets("jun")
        erow = 21
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 8 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(i, 16).Copy
                Worksheets("test").Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Cells(i, 3).Copy
                Worksheets("test").Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Cells(i, 2).Copy
                Worksheets("test").Cells(erow, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Cells(i, 6).Copy
                Worksheets("test").Cells(erow, 5).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                erow = erow + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

The easiest solution would be to make a very large number of blank rows that will be then pasted but there must be a more elegant solution since if I have only a few items to paste this is not practical.

I want to leave two blank spaces i.e. row 22 and 23 as in the picture now and afterwards as final row I want row 24 always.

Comment: Do the new items replace the older ones? I see that the sheets are months, and you accumulate them in a test sheet. is this correct?

Comment: Yes you got it! Ideally I would like to create a new test sheet for the same template for every month so they shouldn't replace the old ones. Instead create a new worksheet of this template and insert the rows in the way I described in my question. However, I haven't gotten that far into how to do that yet :).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for my original question sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

Read the comments and adjust it to fit your needs

Note: Code lacks error control

```
Public Sub CopyData()
    
    ' Define the object variables
    Dim templateWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim newWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Define other variables
    Dim newSheetName As String
    
    
    
    Dim lastSourceRow As Long
    Dim startSourceRow As Long
    Dim lastTargetRow As Long
    Dim sourceRowCounter As Long
    Dim columnCounter As Long
    
    Dim columnsToCopy As Variant
    Dim columnsDestination As Variant
    
    ' Adjust the worksheets names
    Set templateWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    Set sourceWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    
    ' Ask for the new sheet name
    newSheetName = InputBox("Enter new sheet name")
    
    ' Add the new sheet
    Set newWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    ' Rename it
    newWorksheet.Name = newSheetName
    
    ' Define the number of columns to copy from one sheet to the other
    columnsToCopy = Array(1, 5, 21, 27, 29, 231)
    columnsDestination = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) ' -> This must have the same items' quantity as columnsToCopy
        
    ' Adjust the initial row
    startSourceRow = 8
    
    ' Find the number of the last row in source sheet (notice that this search in column A = 1)
    lastSourceRow = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For sourceRowCounter = startSourceRow To lastSourceRow
                
        ' Get last row on target sheet (notice that this search in column A = 1)
        lastTargetRow = newWorksheet.Cells(newWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For columnCounter = 0 To UBound(columnsToCopy)
            
            ' You don't need to use copy and paste if values is all that you're passing (otherwise use the copy destination method)
            newWorksheet.Cells(lastTargetRow, columnsDestination(columnCounter)).Offset(1, 0).Value = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceRowCounter, columnsToCopy(columnCounter)).Value
        
        Next columnCounter
                    
    Next sourceRowCounter
    
    ' If this is necessary...
    sourceWorksheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Let me know if it helps